# Get pid who comunnicate over COM1

Tags: linux, serial-port, debian

Can I see PID who uses COM1 in Debian from start os and if can how ?
Is there any log file for this ?

Comment: Do you want to do this programattically? Or as an administrative tool?

Comment: Admin tool. I need to read just this, I have problem with this port so I want to see who uses this.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is to simply:

```
$ fuser /dev/ttyS0
```

Note that this will only show processes from your own user, unless you're root.

The kernel does not directly log when processes open the serial port. There are a number of options if you need to log:

1. Periodically log the output of `fuser /dev/ttyS0` or `lsof /dev/ttyS0`.
2. Restrict access to `/dev/ttyS0` to a special-purpose user, and use `sudo` or some other gateway program to gain access to it. This will leave logs when the gateway program is invoked.

Comment: No, this shows only the current user. No logs are kept of processes opening the ttyS0 device. If you want logs, you can fuser periodically and log the results, or you can restrict access to root and write some kind of gateway program to control and log access (but this requires modifications to the programs/scripts using ttyS0)

Comment: Do you have that script ? I am not familiar with bash at all.

Comment: No, I'm afraid writing such a script from scratch would be more effort than I like to give away for free on online Q&A sites :) If you're looking for a premade solution, ask on serverfault.com if anyone knows of such a premade solution